# Hibernate Criteria - timestamp queries always evaluated as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, timestamp

I am making a query with Hibernate Criteria to get all users after a certain timestamp, for some reason i always receive this error (`Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp`) but this is incorrect as this was the criteria (`CriteriaImpl(com.tradeit.services.data.model.User:this[][updatedAt>2016-01-01 00:00:00.0])`) as you can see the timestamp is 2016-01-01 00:00:00 and not 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

The users updatedAt field is of type java.sql.Timestamp:

```
class User {
  ...
  private Timestamp updatedAt;
  ...
  public Timestamp getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
  }

  public void setUpdatedAt(Timestamp updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
  }
}

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.tradeit.services.data.model.User" table="User">
    ...
    <property name="updatedAt" type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
    ...
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And here is the log output:

```
16:03:09,538 INFO  [TILogger] (default task-10) Getting list for criteria: CriteriaImpl(com.tradeit.services.data.model.User:this[][updatedAt>2016-01-01 00:00:00.0])
16:03:09,539 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_10_0_, this_.firstName as firstNam2_10_0_, this_.lastName as lastName3_10_0_, this_.password as password4_10_0_, this_.tempPassword as tempPass5_10_0_, this_.email as email6_10_0_, this_.telephone as telephon7_10_0_, this_.countryId as countryI8_10_0_, this_.channels as channels9_10_0_, this_.isRegistered as isRegis10_10_0_, this_.isAdmin as isAdmin11_10_0_, this_.isOnTrial as isOnTri12_10_0_, this_.tempPasswordRequestTime as tempPas13_10_0_, this_.lastPayment as lastPay14_10_0_, this_.updatedAt as updated15_10_0_, this_.createdAt as created16_10_0_ from User this_ where this_.updatedAt>?

16:03:09,545 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-10) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
16:03:09,545 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-10) Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
16:03:09,546 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-10) UT005023: Exception handling request to /services/rest/Users/query: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

The strange part is that i have other classes that also have an updatedAt timestamp and the same exact queries work but for some reason only with the User  class the timestamp somehow loses its value and becomes 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I have gone over everything to try and find something that differs between the User class, table and mappings with the other classes, tables and mappings and they are all the same type with the same exact mappings and everything.

Comment: please check your DB, you probably has values '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in database.  for MySQL '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is a valid date but it cannot be converted to java.sql.Timestamp. You can add zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull to your datasource connection string in order all zeroes ('0000-00-00') will be converted to NULL

Comment: @algor thank you that was the problem, one of the values for one of the users timestamp fields was 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and when it tried to extract the value it created that error, i thought the problem was with the query not with the database.